# Why does windows GDI use RGBA format for `COLORREF` instead of BGRA?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, rgb

[MSDN states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183449.aspx):

> When specifying an explicit RGB color, the COLORREF value has the
> following hexadecimal form:
>
> 0x00bbggrr
>
> The low-order byte contains a
> value for the relative intensity of red; the second byte contains a
> value for green; and the third byte contains a value for blue. The
> high-order byte must be zero. The maximum value for a single byte is
> 0xFF.

From `wingdi.h`

```
#define RGB(r,g,b)          ((COLORREF)((BYTE)(r) | ((BYTE)(g) << 8) | ((BYTE)(b) << 16)))

#define GetRValue(rgb)      ((BYTE)  (rgb) )
#define GetGValue(rgb)      ((BYTE) ((rgb) >> 8))
#define GetBValue(rgb)      ((BYTE) ((rgb) >> 16))
```

As windows is little endian, `COLORREF` is in RGBA format. This looks strange because isn't the color format that Windows use internally, BGR(A)?

The [`RGBQUAD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162938.aspx) structure is defined as

```
typedef struct tagRGBQUAD {
  BYTE rgbBlue;
  BYTE rgbGreen;
  BYTE rgbRed;
  BYTE rgbReserved;
} RGBQUAD;
```

which is, unlike `COLORREF`, BGRA.

Since the `bitblt` function expects an array of `COLORREF` values, this means that there is always an additional conversion going on from RGBA to BGRA during every call, if Windows use BGRA as its native format.

I don't remember correctly, but I also read somewhere that there is a strange mix in the pixel format used in the winapi.

Can someone please explain?

Comment: Your assertion is untrue; the macros clearly assemble COLORREF in 0x00bbggrr order.  Look at them again, or write some code using them and observe the result.

Comment: Windows uses the OS/2 format for BMP files, and OS/2 format differs in a few ways from what Windows would otherwise prefer. One is what you already noticed: The R and B are flipped. Another is that OS/2 bitmaps are bottom-up instead of top-down.

Comment: @RaymondChen Exactly! I always have to put a `-` when specifying the height of the bitmap because of that.. Then is there a way to blit without going through the RGB format conversion in GDI?

Comment: You can select the DIB into a DC and blt directly from it. GDI will do the color flipping as necessary.

Comment: The BGRA structure actually means the colour format is ARGB, a DWORD or 4 byte int reads from the end. Isn't that right?  I'm trying to figure out how to store a colour in a struct, and if I want the colour format (at the 32 bit or 4 byte level) to be RGBA, then I have to store the numbers in the struct as ABGR (backwards). When the int, or whole colour is read, it starts reading from THE END of the struct.

Comment: So the RGB macro creates an 0x 00 BB GG RR and the RBGQuad struct is 0x 00 RR GG BB, one being ABGR and the other ARGB?

Answer (score 2):

COLORREFs date way back to when there was much less standardization in pixel formats.  Many graphics adapters were still using palettes rather than full 24- or 32-bit color, so even if your adapter required a byte re-order, you didn't need to do very many of them.  Some graphics adapters even stored images in separate color planes rather than a single plane of multi-channel colors.  There was no "right" answer back then.

RGBQUADs came from the BMP format, which as Raymond Chen mentioned in the comments, comes from the OS/2 bitmap format.